# Loop to iterate join over columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('s1', 's2'),
       ('s1', 's3'),
       ('s2', 's4'),
       ('s3', 's5'),
       ('s5', 's6')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['start', 'end'])
+-----+---+
|start|end|
+-----+---+
|   s1| s2|
|   s1| s3|
|   s2| s4|
|   s3| s5|
|   s5| s6|
+-----+---+
```

I want to see if the `end column` has values from the `start column` and write their values in a new `end2 column`

```
new_df = df
df = df.join(new_df , (df.start== new_df.end))
```

The result is something like this:

```
+-----+---+----+
|start|end|end2|
+-----+---+----+
|   s1| s2|  s4|
|   s1| s3|  s5|
|   s2| s4|null|
|   s3| s5|  s6|
|   s5| s6|null|
+-----+---+----+
```

Then I want to join again to see if `end2` has values in `start` and write their values from the `end` column to the new `end3` column. And **so do the join until the last column is filled with all the None values**

That is, an iterative join along the columns comes out (there are actually a lot more rows in my dataframe, so writing each join is not very good). But I don't understand how to do it. The result should be something like this

```
while df[-1].notnull():
     df = df.join... #join ends columns
     new_df[] =  #add new column


+-----+---+----+----+----+
|start|end|end2|end3|end4|
+-----+---+----+----+----+
|   s1| s2|  s4|None|None|
|   s1| s3|  s5|  s6|None|
|   s2| s4|None|None|None|
|   s3| s5|  s6|None|None|
|   s5| s6|None|None|None|
+-----+---+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mapping the original dictionary to the end column, using start as the key, and end as the values:

```
df.assign(end2 = df['end'].map(dict(df.to_records(index=False))))
```

Output:

```
  start end end2
0    s1  s2   s4
1    s1  s3   s5
2    s2  s4  NaN
3    s3  s5   s6
4    s5  s6  NaN
```

To create all possible columns, we can use a while loop:

```
i = 2
m = dict(df.to_records(index=False))
while df.iloc[:,-1].count() != 0:
    df['end{}'.format(i)] =  df.iloc[:,-1].map(m)
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
  start end end2 end3 end4
0    s1  s2   s4  NaN  NaN
1    s1  s3   s5   s6  NaN
2    s2  s4  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    s3  s5   s6  NaN  NaN
4    s5  s6  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: but i need create end3, end4 e.t.c...

Comment: i made an edit.